# Shading Issue with Array

Tags: modifiers, shaders

I have created a simple mesh that I would like to array. However, when I use an array there is visible distortion in the shading where the array meets (highlighted in red here, I'm viewing it using the metal carpaint matcap, but it shows up on other glossy matcaps, too):

[image]

I think it *may* be a topology issue, but I just can't figure it out! The .blend file is available [here](https://pasteall.org/blend/9354c8b65cdf46459f29f56582a2fa8e) if anyone wishes to take a look.

I would like to understand what is happening and what I can do to fix this issue. So far, I have enabled/applied the following:

- Shade Smooth
- Auto Smooth
- Recalculate Normals
- Rotation and Scale
- Merge by Distance (after I applied the modifier)

Your help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you set the merge option in the array modifier?

Comment: Hi @MartyFouts, I have. I've also set merge first and last (though there is no need to do so in this instance).

Comment: If you add a horizontal loopcut across those faces and pull it out slightly to match the curve it cures the problem.  I guess it happens because Blender is trying to bend a flat face. The others are probably ok because they're a bit smaller.

Comment: Also add a loopcut and slide it up close to your indentations. If that helps I'll try to add it with images as an answer a bit later.

Comment: Hi @JohnEason, thanks for replying. The horizontal loopcut kind of worked... it does smooth out the jagged shading, but the bad shading has moved up to the top most face. I also tried adding vertical loopcuts close to the indentations, but again there is always a badly shaded face at the edges of the mesh.

Comment: A bit out of my comfort zone I'm afraid. You'll have to wait until someone more experienced answers in that case.

Comment: Hi @JohnEason, no problem, thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: set autosmooth to 22 degrees? but honestly, i did not check for "other" complications then...

Comment: the *Weighted Normal* modifier could be an option, too, with vertex group? I'm not sure how it should look like.